# Setting custom root TLS certificates for QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, ssl-error

I use QGIS on Linux in an enterprise setting, where the IT department runs a MitM firewall which puts in its own root certificate on all HTTPS traffic. This made using the OSM basemaps in QGIS annoying already, which frequent TLS error messages, but recently I have stopped getting the errors which let me ignore the untrusted root and instead rendering the OSM tiles broken. Is there a way to customize QGIS's TLS trust settings? I have the certificate bundle, but I can't figure out how to get QGIS to use it.

QGIS is running as a Flatpak on RHEL 8.

Comment: The certificates are added to the main OS things, but I've installed it as a flatpak (we're running RHEL 8) which seems to prevent it from picking up the certificate bundle.

Comment: Try allowing access to host `/etc/`.  A gui way of doing this is via the [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) flatpak app.

Comment: I tried adding permissions to /etc, but it doesn't seem to help. Googling around a bit, it's likely because the Flatpak container ships with is own set of trusted CA certificates, so it doesn't see the local certs, and there doesn't seem to be a standard way to pass-through this stuff. I think I may just set up a reverse proxy to OSM running locally instead.

Comment: Oh, but that's exactly the config setting I failed to find on my own! Thank you for pointing out that it did indeed exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the certificate to the QGIS certificate store

- Settings

  - Options

    - Authentication (Manage Certificates)

[image]